# Py2exe - window disappears immediately after running

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, executable, py2exe

I built windows executable from python gui application with py2exe. 
My setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe
    setup(windows=[{"script":"main.py"}],options={"py2exe":{"includes":["sip","PyQt4.QtGui"]}})
```

When I run the exe generated by py2exe, window shows up and disappears immediately.
I can't figure out what is wrong. Could you give me some suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you launching by double-clicking the executable?  If so, try launching from the command line and you will probably see an error message.

Comment: Open a `cmd` and execute the exe in there, so you can see if there's an exception or something. But also make sure that your program actually does something - in case of a Qt application, you have to start the main loop with `app._exec()` or it will quit immediately.

Comment: at the end of you python script add `raw_input("")`

Comment: I have already tried to run from the command line - the same result and there is no error message.

Comment: Thank you Grijesh. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've solved it with the instruction found on this comment

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17999421/1891624

Just adding this code in my setup.py

```
import py2exe
py2exe.build_exe.py2exe.old_prepare = py2exe.build_exe.py2exe.plat_prepare
def new_prep(self):
  self.old_prepare()
  from _tkinter import TK_VERSION, TCL_VERSION
  self.dlls_in_exedir.append('tcl{0}.dll'.format(TCL_VERSION.replace('.','')))
  self.dlls_in_exedir.append('tk{0}.dll'.format(TK_VERSION.replace('.','')))
py2exe.build_exe.py2exe.plat_prepare = new_prep
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end of your code

```
input('')
```

This will prevent the window from closing until you press enter